UML Features and Classifiers
In the UML specification for 2.5.1, the description of Feature is given in section 9.9.6 on page 180:

A Feature declares a behavioral or structural characteristic of
Classifiers.

Further down, in section 9.9.6.6 "Association Ends", we have the specification of featuringClassifer:

/featuringClassifier : Classifier [0..1]
{union, subsets
A_member_memberNamespace::memberNamespace} (opposite
Classifier::feature)
The Classifiers that have this Feature as a
feature.

To me, the multiplicity given ([0..1]) is problematic -- I cannot find any derivation of Feature whose owner can be anything but a Classifier, and each Element which is not a Package must have exactly one owner Element according to the descriptions given in section 7 under "Commom Structure".
Another thing (probably just a typo, but could lead to trouble) is the last sentence: "The Classifiers that have this Feature as a feature". Note that it says (plural) "classifiers" and not singular "classifier".
In earlier sections of the specification (section 6.1) it is remarked that some multiplicities were relaxed from having lowerBound == 1 to lowerBound == 0:

A small number of lower multiplicities have been relaxed from 1 to 0,
in order to represent default values that cannot be formally
represented  using MOF. In these cases the absence of a value
signifies the presence of a default value. These cases could not be
represented at all in earlier  versions of UML. They all occur in
Clause 15: Activities and are made  explicit in the text there.

However, Feature is not in Clause 15.
To me, a Feature must be owned by some kind of Classifier, either a Class, an Association, or an AssociationClass. Can anyone come up with a different scenario where a Feature (which is an abstract base class for Attributes, Operations, etc.) would be owned by something other than a Classifier? And if not, why can't featuringClassifier simply subset its owner Element?

You really ask difficult questions! It's not like you are working on a thesis about UML?

In the meantime, it appears that indirectly, featuringClassifier must subset owner because it subsets memberNamespace (Feature is a RedefinableElement, which is a NamedElement). Although memberNamespace can have non-owned NamedElements due to package import, etc., it still doesn't make sense that Feature could be owned directly by anything other than a Classifier which would be in its derived union namespace (which DOES subset owner).

Unfortunately my mind isn't free enough to dive in. However, I found it useful to import the UML metamodel into an UML tool in order to navigate. It's not that well documented as it should be, but seeing relations is a lot easier than in the PDF.

Actually, there is a possible other owner for a Feature: A Property can be owned by another Property as its qualifier.
Removing the plural of "classifers" has been missed by Issue UML22-382.


Thanks! Going back to my original question, in the UML spec there is no OCL implementation given for /featuringClassifier which is a derived union. Although the multiplicity given is [0..1], what is the intended derivation? If owner of the Feature (or Property) is another Property, there should be a Classifier at the end of the chain of ownership. If I were implementing the derivation myself, should I return an empty set (in OCL) or null if owner is not a Classifier? Or should I attempt to find the owner at the end of the chain?
